# SSIS BIDS 2008 FOREACH Loop Container w/File Enumerator Reset During Process

Tags: c#, sql-server, foreach, ssis

I'm using C# in BIDS 2008.
I have a FOREACH LOOP container with a specific location for files.
My objective is to be able to add files to folder, while foreach loop is processing and the container picks them up for processing.
My thoughts would be to add a script component that forces the folder evaluation process for files to occur at the end of each loop.
Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Reason:  I'm processing two years of daily files.  During the processing I expect a couple of days to pass.  I want to just add the daily file to the folder and the loop to process it without restarting the ssis package.

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

I can think of a few ways to accomplish this without even needing a Script Task.  You could just process from the original folder and move to a processed folder when complete or and error folder when the import fails. (conditional precedence).

If you really want to move folders into another folder and process in smaller chunks you could use 2 for each loops and a int variable to count.  So the outer loop moves the files to a folder that the inner loop then enumerates and uses.

But I agree with @Pirate X a more concrete example will get you a better more detailed and on point answer.